# How would you set up a database to handle comments for a blogging site?

Tags: database-design, relational-database

I'm a student learning about database design and currently learning about the relationships of - one-to-one, one-to-many, many-to-many. I understand the concept well enough, but feel like I'm lacking experience/information on how it would be implemented in a real production scenario.

My question is this

> If I have a blog website with a Blog Post as an entity and comments for each blog post, how would you handle the comments in the database?`

Would you use a one-to-many relationship and just store all the comments in a single table. Then link those comments to each blog post and user who created it?

What if each comment had a sub-comment? Would you create a separate table for sub-comments and link it to a single comment? Would that cause too much overhead and confusion within the DB itself?

I get the concepts and all, but don't understand best practices for handling what seems like basic stuff.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do other people do?

Comment: I keep looking around, all the info seems convoluted or  incomplete. Do you have a link of some sort I could read? Would love to do that as well! @Strawberry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution is to stick with a one-to-many relationship. Use one table and store one comment per row, with references to the post and the comment author, and a timestamp so you can sort the comments chronologically.

You seem uncertain about whether you need a "threaded comment" hierarchy. This is more complex, so [if you don't need it, don't bother](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it).

If you do need to show comment threads, then you should learn about running recursive queries in MySQL 8.0: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html#common-table-expressions-recursive

You still only need one table. Don't create a second table for sub-comments. Just store comments like in your one-to-many example, but each comment may link to its "parent" comment when it is a reply.

Another solution that many sites use is to skip implementing their own comment system, and just embed a comment service like [Disqus](https://disqus.com). That's likely to be much more reliable and safe than yours. But if you're doing this as a learning exercise, that's worthwhile too.

Comment: Bill, thank you for your answer! That clears up quite a bit. I'm doing this all for a learning exercise. So I appreciate the help. I'm not actually building anything for production, just testing stuff out to understand the stuff I'm being taught in class on a practical level. It's easy for me to just sit and class and say, "Ya one-to-many relationship, i can answer that on a multiple choice'! And another to think and do it in practice

Comment: It's definitely true that writing code and getting the experience of making it work is valuable and necessary to becoming a software developer. Don't be afraid of making mistakes, as long as you learn from them.